# List unpushed commits in all branches

Tags: git, push, commit

I am currently working on a project with a team. This project has many branches developed in parallel.

Here is the problem I encountered: I am working on several branches, committing as much as possible. And apparently, sometimes I forget to push the commits once I finished working on a branch. This leads to have unpushed changes for long time, and of course, other members of the team would work on these "unfixed" branches and it might cause problems. And at no time, while working on other branches, git tells me that I have unpushed commits on other branches than the current one.

Is there a command, similar to `git cherry -v`, that would indicates unpushed commits on all branches?

I noticed that I could use `git cherry -v origin/branchA branchA` to display unpushed commit of branchA from any branch. It is quite close to what I am looking for, but I want it for all branches at the same time. Is there a way to generalize it to all branches? (I don't expect to remember on which branch I forgot to push)

Comment: it doesn't use cherry, but `git branch -vv` provides a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple script :

(In your .bashrc)

```
alias git-list-unpushed='git for-each-ref --format "%(refname)" | grep "refs/remotes" | sed "s@refs/remotes/@@" | while read branch; do echo "$branch"; git cherry -v "$branch" "${branch/origin\//}"; done'
```

You can then run git-list-unpushed to see a summary of all unpushed commits for each branch

Comment: I hoped to find a git command... But nevertheless, I tried this script (I am not familiar with scripts so I don't understand everything), and it doesn't work. I get a lot of garbage (`fatal: Unknown commit` for every commit) and I can't see the unpushed changes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on edi9999’s idea, I created the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

branches=$(git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:short):%(refname:short)' refs/heads)
for raw_branch in $branches; do
  remote_branch=$(cut -d ':' -f 1 <<< "$raw_branch")
  local_branch=$(cut -d ':' -f 2 <<< "$raw_branch")

  echo $local_branch
  if [ "x$remote_branch" == "x" ]; then
    echo WARNING: No remote branch!
  else
    git cherry -v "$remote_branch" "$local_branch"
  fi

  echo
done
```

Because the `:` is always present, `cut` should be good.